# Illustrator: Export for Screens dimensions off by 1 pixel and exporting with poor image quality

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, dimensions

I'm trying to export a number of artboards containing web ads of various sizes.

(728x90, 300x600, 300x250. etc.)

I'm finding it difficult to export in the selected dimensions WHILE maintaining good quality.

I'm also finding that some are exporting with an extra pixel... (1200x1200 is exporting as 1201x1201)

Any tips for a dummy trying to finalize his first web display ads would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What are your export settings in Illustrator for the images and how are you exporting the artboards?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. I tried a 600x300px web document, placed some graphics and text, and output using Export for Screens. The result is 600 x 300, and the quality is perfect. I also tried exporting at 2x size, and again perfect result 1200 x 600px.  Perhaps you might want to share the result you are getting so we can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

Your graphics are exporting with an extra pixel because your artboard position has a decimal in it. To check this, go to Window -> Properties. Select the artboard tool (Shift+O). To fix this, just make sure your X and Y end in a 0.

[image: Properties Panel]

Your graphics might look bad depending on your export quality and anti-aliasing options. You can change this when going to File -> Export -> Export for Screens. Then select the gear icon (next to the word Android). You can then change the anti-aliasing options depending on the file format you export in.

[image: anti-aliasing]

Answer (score 0):

You should also make elements of your design pixel perfect. To do this, select the element and right click. There should be an option in the list "Make pixel perfect". There are other ways (e.g. using the menu bar) but I find this the most convenient way. Bear in mind that, by necessity, the element will resize and move around slightly to achieve this. I usually create a rectangle with no stroke and fill to the exact size of the finished graphic, make it pixel perfect as described above, then resize the artboard to that rectangle. You can delete the rectangle once you've done this, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might help is make sure that your artboard is lined up (the x and y coordinates) on a whole pixel and doesn't start on a decimal.