# Glitch in output resolution size for same dimension artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, resolution, glitch

I have created 50 artboards in Adobe Illustrator. Their size is the same 59.5x59.5 mm
Nothing else. Just the blank artboards. When I go File > Export > Export as --> JPG and then I choose "Use artboards" then "Range" > 1 (and do the export) then next step the same "Range" > 2 and so on, the resulting JPGs are different. The first 4 JPGs have a size of 704x704 pixels. But the one corresponding to the artboard number 5 has a different resolution 703x704 pixels. I am working with 300 ppi by the way.

[image: Screenshot of all the identical artboards]

What is going on?

Also they should all be 703x703 if my calculations are correct. (5.95x300)/2.54 = 702.755905511811

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is annoying. There might be some explanation, but I often encounter these kinds of "rounding errors" in Illustrator. Mostly with objects though. In my experience InDesign has a lot less of this. Don't know if it has a different number of decimals or perhaps convert between units in another way.

Comment: It does puzzle me however, *why* you need to do this? I mean if you make vector graphics for print (300 ppi hints this) then why export as jpg instead of PDF? And if you make images for web which needs to be a certain size, why not define the artboard size in pixels?

Comment: Btw: I can reproduce the problem easily. I get both 703x703, 704x704, 703x704, 704x703. But not at the same number artboard as you. Could be related to which spacing you choose?

Comment: @wolff I think you’re right - spacing might be the issue - see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/150598/163497) to a similar issue.

Comment: Check the arboard location @Wolff it might round differently based on where it vegins calculating the pixel.

Comment: @joojaa, you are right. If the origin is in upper left corner of artboard 1 then for example artboard 4 gets wrong dimensions. Also when exported separately. But if I move origin to upper left corner of artboard 4, the dimensions are right. Understandable, but strange way to make it really, but doesn't seem like something we can do anything about.

Comment: Yes you are all right, it depends on position of artboard (having decimals)
So if I were to make a square on those artboards, like in a perimeter, with a width (stroke?) of 1 pixel (I don't know if this is possible), and black color, I would get JPGs with some sides of the square with a black line and some in white?
I was simply playing around, testing the export possibilities and just per chance found out the results weren't the same. It is the first time I use this program. And yes, I find this annoying too :)

Comment: @demklad the reason this probably hasnt been spotted or fixed is that its very unlikely many illustrator users simply wouldnt care, after all if you draw vecrors why would you care about pixel perfect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need pixel precision, then I'd suggest you use one of the "Web" document presets for creating the initial document, to ensure it's set up with *Align Art to Pixel Grid* enabled. I tested this and it seems to fix the problem.

However, if  you choose one of the other document presets, such as one of the "Print" presets, then the *Align Art to Pixel Grid* option is disabled by default. This means that artboards could potentially be located at fractions of a pixel which would (I assume) be the cause of those rounding errors when exporting raster images.

You could of course enable the *Align Art to Pixel Grid* option in any document, then make sure the artboard is a whole number of pixels in both dimensions and also the x and y co-ordinates. Also if you don't like working with this option enabled, you could disable it again once you've got the arboards positioned correctly.

**Edit** further to comments: some of the problem is apparently due to using Export As. Seems to be buggy.  However, Export for Screens works just fine with pixel perfect artboards.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still get different results. I started with the Web preset, made the dimension of the artboards be 168x168 px. X,Y are whole numbers. Height and width are whole numbers. When I click on Object > Make pixel perfect it says "Selected art is already pixel perfect". First artboard exported as JPG is 700x700 The other 2 artboards are 701x700

Comment: I don't think artboards are considered as "objects".  You may have to move them manually to ensure they hit a whole pixel on the grid.

Comment: Hmm I just tested this again, and everything works fine. How are you exporting?  I tried using Export for Screens.

Comment: Export as > JPG

Comment: @demklad. Try export for screens instead.  You can select "jpg" as the format. I tested again with 7 artboards same size as yours. All works fine.

Comment: @demklad did you make sure that the spacing is a whole number of pixels?

Comment: yes everything whole number of pixels, including spacing (Columns 3, Spacing 20 px). I am trying export for screens but not getting anything, as don't really know how to use that option, but keep trying/learning... Did you manage to get same resolution for all the files using "export as" option?

Comment: @demlad - I did another test. Here's [a screenshot](https://imgur.com/dATMb3f) showing 8 artboards output using Export for Screens, all are the same size.

Comment: Here's [my Export for Screens dialog](https://imgur.com/GUl9il6)

Comment: I had to draw something as it complained they were all blank. Now I get the same as you got. But not with the option Export as > JPG

Comment: @demklad - yes the artboards must have content on them to be able to use export for screens.  Export As is older functionality. Export for Screens is fairly new. Adobe has probably rectified the problem with this new feature.

Comment: OK then I think we have established there's a problem somewhere :) I will keep on playing around with this though. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @demklad open the control toolar qnd enter the corner cordinates manually.